# Como colocar a zero ou null numa pesquisa SQL de um intervalo de datas, para aquelas cujo valor não existe?

Tags: mysql, sql

Formula a questão foi um pouco difícil, mas tentarei ser o mais explícito possível usando um exemplo para expor a questão.

Existem os seguintes dados na minha tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objectivo é executar uma consulta `sql` (o SGBD utilizado é o MySQL) no intervalo de data entre 2014-09-01 até 2014-09-10 e ter o resultado seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O que já tenho:**

Para ser sincero ando meio sem ideia de como fazer isso, até ao momento resolvo isso no controle da minha aplicação, um algoritimo como:

1. Selecionar os dados na BD, por meio de um `between` das datas desejadas e guardar numa lista;
2. Para cada dia (ou hora) existente no intervalo da data desejada, guardar em uma variável auxiliar(uma instância de `Calendar` em Java);
3. Verificar se Na lista obtida no ponto 1 existe um elemento com esta data, caso não haver, adiciono um elemento na lista resultante com esta data, mas zero no campo da quantidade;

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso já na consulta em `sql`? A forma como faço agora não é a mais eficiente.

Comment: Cold, você pode criar uma tabela com os períodos (só com datas), e fazer um `left join` com a tabela que você já usa.

Comment: @Wakim se trabalhar com largos intervalos de datas, terei de ter em paralelo uma tabela enorme só para guardar datas?

Comment: Você só precisa de um registro por dia. No pior caso, 3650 linhas para 10 anos. Terá que analisar se o ganho de performance vale a pena, podendo até utilizar um índice.

Comment: Eh... mais estariamos a considerar apenas dias, a minha realizadade são dados estatísticos de com uma precisão considerável : de 10 em 10 segundos. Uma query, a meu ver seia muito mais eficiente, consumiriamos apenas recursos quando necessário e não ocupar memoria física de forma permanente e ter que "joinar" sempre. Porém, se não surgir outra possibilidade, vou pensar em usar algo do género. Obrigado @Wakim

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar um **[gerador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/)** de datas para não precisar de tabelas intermediárias:

```
SELECT
   DATE_ADD( '2014-01-01', INTERVAL d1+d2*10+d3*100 DAY ) AS diaDoAno
FROM
   ( SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t1,
   ( SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t2,
   ( SELECT 0 AS d3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 ) t3
WHERE
   YEAR( DATE_ADD( '2014-01-01', INTERVAL d1+d2*10+d3*100 DAY ) ) = 2014
```

A query fica aparentemente grande, mas a performance é excelente.

**Funcionamento:**

1. Cada *subquery* gera os números de 0 a 9, exceto a última, que gera números de 0 a 3;
2. a fórmula `d1+d2*10+d3*100` transforma as saídas das 3 *subqueries* em um número de `0` a `399`
3. com `DATE_ADD( '2014-01-01', INTERVAL d1+d2*10+d3*100 DAY )` transformamos este número em uma data.
4. Para limitar aos dias do ano em questão, usamos a mesma fórmula que gera a data, para assegurar que não passemos do intervalo de um ano (lembrando que o número de dias varia nos anos bissextos).

**Como usar:**

Conforme descrito em outras respostas, basta usar um `JOIN` com a tabela desejada.

```
SELECT
   DATE_ADD( '2014-01-01', INTERVAL d1+d2*10+d3*100 DAY ) AS dia_do_ano.
   contador,
   quantidade
FROM
   ( SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t1,
   ( SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t2,
   ( SELECT 0 AS d3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 ) t3
LEFT JOIN
    sua_tabela ON dia_do_ano = data_tempo
WHERE
    YEAR( DATE_ADD( '2014-01-01', INTERVAL d1+d2*10+d3*100 DAY ) ) = 2014
```

Obviamente que o exemplo foi complexo para gerar um ano inteiro, mas se for gerar meses do ano, por exemplo, basta algo como

```
SELECT 1 AS mes UNION SELECT 2 UNION SEL... até ...UNION SELECT 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Cold.
Como o Wakin sugeriu e conforme eu estava escrevendo.

Faça uma tabela de datas, e à partir disto um `LEFT JOIN` com sua tabela.

Seguem dois links com sugestões para criação desta tabela:

[Gerar Tabela Datas 1](https://gist.github.com/bryhal/4129042)

[Gerar Tabela Datas 2](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=95)

Para os valores `null`, basta adicionar no seu `COUNT` a verificação `IFNULL()` e seu problema estará solucionado.

Comment: Obrigado @Fernando A.W. pela resposta/sugestão, porém, assim como falei ao wakin, eu teria de ter uma tabela(pelo semelhante a dimensão tempo num D.W) o que se calhar já não seria assim tão eficiente. Se não existir de facto outra forma de o fazer, vou considerar esta via.

Comment: Entendi, depende muito da sua arquitetura e necessidade. Mas se for uma tabela indexada e tudo mais, não seriam muitos registros para vincular, claro, vai depender muito do intervalo que você estaria buscando. Mas em paralelo a isto, você pode usar `hints` de performance para ajudar, segue um exemplo [Hint Performance](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/613.cfm). Fica como dica também. Mas creio que seja uma boa solução.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma **PROCEDURE** criando uma **tabela temporária** antes de executar a consulta, por exemplo:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE TempDateTable(data_ini DATE, data_fim DATE)

BEGIN
    DECLARE v_curdate DATE;
    SET @v_curdate = data_ini;
    START TRANSACTION;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdatetable;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempdatetable  (
        data_tempo DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    );

  WHILE @v_curdate <= data_fim DO
    INSERT INTO `TempDateTable`(`data_tempo`) VALUES (@v_curdate);
    SET @v_curdate = ADDDATE(@v_curdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
  COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Dados**

```
--------------------------------------
| data_tempo | contador | quantidade |
--------------------------------------
| 2014-09-01 | CDR_SUC  | 256        |
| 2014-09-04 | CDR_SUC  | 258        |
| 2014-09-05 | CDR_SUC  | 195        |
| 2014-09-06 | CDR_SUC  | 100        |
| 2014-09-10 | CDR_SUC  | 317        |
--------------------------------------
```

**Executando Procedure**

```
CALL `databasetest`.`TempDateTable`('2014-09-01', '2014-09-10');
```

**Realizando a consulta**

```
SELECT tmp.data_tempo, test.contador, IFNULL(test.quantidade,0) 
FROM tempdatetable as tmp 
    LEFT JOIN  testedados as  test ON DATE(test.data_tempo) = DATE(tmp.data_tempo);
```

**Resultado:**

```
--------------------------------------
| data_tempo | contador | quantidade |
--------------------------------------
| 2014-09-01 | CDR_SUC  | 256        |
| 2014-09-02 | NULL     | 0          |
| 2014-09-03 | NULL     | 0          |
| 2014-09-04 | CDR_SUC  | 258        |
| 2014-09-05 | CDR_SUC  | 195        |
| 2014-09-06 | CDR_SUC  | 100        |
| 2014-09-07 | NULL     | 0          |
| 2014-09-08 | NULL     | 0          |
| 2014-09-09 | NULL     | 0          |
| 2014-09-10 | CDR_SUC  | 317        |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Obrigado @KaduAmaral pela resposta, mas acredito que, assim como comentei com Fernando A.W. na resposta dele, eu estaria  a criar sempre uma dimensão de tempo (como num D.W.). E o mais incviavél para min seria ter uma dimensão auxiliar, ou seja, que é sempre criada quando for feita uma consulta. Para cada consulta eu tenho uma tabela criada com o tempo (em ordem de 10 segundos) com uns tantos registos...

Comment: E se não me engano o resultado aí é meio diferente do meu neh amigão... kkkkk. Só pra notar que os contadores podem diversificar.

Comment: A diferença que tu fala é o campo `contador`? Mas está tranquilo, se existe uma outra maneira de fazer isso, está além dos meus conhecimentos com SQL. Ou seja, que eu saiba só em algorítimo mesmo.

Comment: Pois é @KaduAmaral, porém já tenho esta opção como backup :D.