# Como gerar sequências numéricas em SQL sem precisar criar tabelas?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Lendo a pergunta [Como colocar a zero ou null numa pesquisa SQL de um intervalo de datas, para aquelas cujo valor não existe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33828/101) eu lembrei de um problema semelhante que tenho. Normalmente quando preciso dessas sequências que se relacionem com intervalo de dados eu utilizo tabelas auxiliares para controlar isto. Eu imagino que esta não seja uma solução muito boa mas não tenho ideia como resolver isto sem elas.

Há alguma maneira de gerar estas sequências sem a necessidade de uma nova tabela?

Minha intenção não é específica para um banco de dados, prefiro uma solução geral, mas se tiver alguma razão para funcionar só em um banco de dados, vá em frente, responda para o que você sabe que funciona de forma específica.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nestes casos, uma solução performática é usar geradores. A solução inicial funciona em praticamente qualquer SGBD com suporte a SQL. Veja mais ao final da resposta as soluções otimizadas para SGBDs específicos.

Segue um exemplo que produz números de 0 a 999:

```
SELECT d1+d2*10+d3*100 AS gerador FROM
   ( SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t1,
   ( SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t2,
   ( SELECT 0 AS d3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t3
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0399/1)**.

**Funcionamento:**

- Cada um dos `SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 ... SELECT 9` gera números de 0 a 9;
- o que fizemos no exemplo inicial foi combinar 3 deles, para ter 3 casas decimais. A fórmula `d1+d2*10+d3*100` serve para converter as 3 saídas de cada gerador em um número inteiro.

Dependendo do SGBD pode ser necessário o uso de `UNION ALL` em vez de apenas `UNION`.

**Otimizando para usos mais específicos:**

- Se precisar de números de 1 a 780, basta ajustar a fórmula e usar um `LIMIT 780`, por exemplo.
- nada impede de se evitar a multiplicação trocando a escala nas subqueries:

  ```
  SELECT d1 + d2 AS gerador FROM
   ( SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t1,
   ( SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40
     UNION SELECT 50 UNION SELECT 60 UNION SELECT 70 UNION SELECT 80 UNION SELECT 90 ) t2
  ```

  Neste exemplo o segundo conjunto de `SELECT`s está otimizado com os números * 10 já.
- se precisar de números de 0 a 255, é muito melhor usar uma query mais curta:

  ```
  SELECT d1+d2*4+d3*16+d4*64 AS gerador FROM
     ( SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) t1,
     ( SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) t2,
     ( SELECT 0 AS d3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) t3,
     ( SELECT 0 AS d4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) t4
  ```

  Neste caso a lógica foi a seguinte: 4 ^ 4 = 256, então usamos 4 *queries*, mas com 4 dígitos em cada. O importante é entender o funcionamento do gerador, pois há varias maneiras de se otimizar o código.
- Gerando datas

  Podemos restringir o 3º dígito do exemplo inicial a apenas 3, pois de 0 a 399 é suficiente para cobrir um ano inteiro. O DATE_ADD é uma solução para gerar uma data:

  ```
  DATE_ADD( '2014-01-01', INTERVAL d1+d2*10+d3*100 DAY )
  ```

  e basta um `WHERE` para restringir a saída ao intervalo de um ano. Veja na **[outra pergunta](/a/33858/70)** que você mencionou uma resposta com o exemplo completo.

### Soluções proprietárias:

**MS SQL Server**

No MS SQL Server temos como simplificar um bocado usando uma função. Notar o cuidado de limitar a recursividade com `MAXRECURSION 0`:

```
WITH gerador (id) AS (
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id + 1
     FROM gerador
     WHERE id < 1000000
  )
  SELECT TOP 1000 id FROM gerador
  OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
GO
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0399/1)**.

**PostgreSQL**

Mais simples ainda, com a função `generate_series`:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series ( 1, 1000 )
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/b0399/1)**.

**Oracle**

O Oracle tem na instalação padrão uma [tabela especial chamada dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table), com uma série de pseudo-colunas para usos especiais. Exemplo para nossa questão:

```
SELECT level FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 1000
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfbed/3)**.

### Complementando:

Inicialmente a pergunta põe a condição de não ter uma tabela para isso. De qualquer forma, uma solução intermediária, mas muito interessante caso estas sequências sejam necessárias em muitas ocasiões, é você ter uma tabela de inteiros:

```
CREATE TABLE inteiros (i INT);
INSERT INTO inteiros (i) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);
```

Assim, você pode usar as técnicas acima combinando esta tabela no lugar dos `SELECT UNION`:

```
SELECT d3.i*100+d2.i*10+d1.i+1 AS gerador
FROM inteiros AS d1
JOIN inteiros AS d2
JOIN inteiros AS d3;
```

Comment: Então posso concluir que no MySQL ou SQLite a solução teria que ser a mais geral?

Comment: @bigown infelizmente no MySQL eu ainda preciso da solução genérica inicial mesmo (digo isso, pq uso bastante o MySQL na prática). No SQLite a coisa pode ficar mais interessante: se a implementação escolhida for _embedded_, é relativamente simples implementar uma função nativa similar à do PostgreSQL. Se for usar um conector de terceiros, a solução genérica resolve. Lembrando que apesar da _query_ ficar "volumosa", a performance da solução genérica é muito boa.

Answer (score 0):

O que você deve fazer e criar uma `SEQUENCE` que possui compatibilidade:

> O comando `CREATE SEQUENCE` está em conformidade com o padrão SQL, com as seguintes exceções:
>
> - Não é suportada a expressão do padrão `AS`
> - A obtenção do próximo valor é feita usando a função nextval()
>     em vez da expressão do padrão `NEXT VALUE FOR`.
> - A cláusula `OWNED BY` é uma extensão do PostgreSQL.

Neste link : [Criar Sequence](http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg82/sql-createsequence.html) possui uma Documentação do PostgreSQL 8.2.0 detalhada explicando e exemplificando possíveis casos da criação de Sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As SEQUENCES são objetos do SGBD para gerar valores de auto numeração, onde podemos definir os valores iniciais e seus incrementos.

Aqui vai um exemplo de criação de sequence no Oracle:

```
create sequence SEQ_EXAMPLE
  minvalue 1
  maxvalue 999
  start with 1
  increment by 1
  nocache
  nocycle;
```

Os seus parâmetros significam respectivamente que o valor mínimo de 1(minvalue 1), o máximo de 999(maxvalue 999), inicia em 1(start with 1), será incrementada por 1(increment by 1), não irá prealocar valores para esta sequence (nocache) e ao atingir o máximo não irá para o valor mínimo(no cycle).

Para obter o valor atual da sequence:

```
 SELECT SEQ_EXAMPLE.currval
```

Para obter o próximo valor da sequence:

```
SELECT SEQ_EXAMPLE.nextval
```

Para usá-la na criação de sua tabela, neste caso como chave:

```
INSERT INTO exemplo_tb (NR_SEQUENCIA, NOME, LOGIN)
VALUES (SEQ_EXAMPLE.Nextval, 'Fulaninho', 'ful');
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT level
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY level <=12;
```