# Retornar quais dos itens da consulta não constam na tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql

Há alguma maneira de retornar quais itens da consulta não constam numa tabela?

Digamos que eu tenha uma consulta assim:

```
SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE id IN (1,23,45,68,91,126,345,418,509,610);
```

Isso irá me trazer uma tabela com os registros da consulta que **estão presentes** no sistema. Mas eu quero saber quais desses registros foram apagados, então preciso dos itens que **não estão** presentes no sistema.

Como resolver isso sem ter que fazer uma consulta pra cada registro?

Poderia resolver isso criando uma tabela temporária com os valores buscados e fazer um LEFT JOIN com a tabela do sistema buscando por NULL na comparação. Mas teria alguma forma mais simples de retornar os valores ausentes?

Comment: É uma boa pergunta. Porém, se estiver fazendo isso em alguma linguagem de programação (Java, PHP, C#) seria mais simples recuperar os IDs existentes em um vetor e fazer um *diff* do resultado com o vetor de IDs original.

Answer (score 4):

> Poderia resolver isso criando uma tabela temporária com os valores buscados e fazer um LEFT JOIN com a tabela do sistema buscando por NULL na comparação. Mas teria alguma forma mais simples de retornar os valores ausentes?

Na minha opinião, a tabela temporária é a saída mais simples. Uma alternativa é usar um monte de `UNION`, mas fica bem feio:

```
SELECT id FROM
   (SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 23 AS id UNION SELECT 45 AS id /* etc */) tbl
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tabela)
```

Demo em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/812b5/12

---

Você também pode usar um truque interessante descrito [nesta resposta do Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33860/74) à pergunta *[Como gerar sequências numéricas em SQL sem precisar criar tabelas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/como-gerar-sequ%C3%AAncias-num%C3%A9ricas-em-sql-sem-precisar-criar-tabelas)* A ideia é manter no seu banco uma tabela de inteiros, com 10 linhas (os números de 0 a 9):

```
CREATE TABLE inteiros (i INT);
INSERT INTO inteiros (i) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);
```

Com essa tabela você consegue simular um gerador, já que o MySQL não dá suporte nativo a geradores. Por exemplo, você consegue gerar os números de 1 a 1000 assim:

```
SELECT d3.i*100+d2.i*10+d1.i+1 AS gerador
FROM inteiros AS d1
JOIN inteiros AS d2
JOIN inteiros AS d3;
```

Aplicando isso ao seu exemplo, e considerando que os ids a serem checados estão nessa faixa de 0 a 1000, a seguinte query gera a lista:

```
SELECT d3.i*100+d2.i*10+d1.i+1 AS gerador
FROM inteiros AS d1
JOIN inteiros AS d2
JOIN inteiros AS d3
HAVING gerador IN (1,23,45,68,91,126,345,418,509,610);
```

Finalmente, usando isso para obter o resultado que você deseja:

```
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT d3.i*100+d2.i*10+d1.i+1 AS id
    FROM inteiros AS d1
    JOIN inteiros AS d2
    JOIN inteiros AS d3
    HAVING gerador IN (1,23,45,68,91,126,345,418,509,610);
) tbl
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tabela)
```

Comment: +1. Eu ia sugerir o mesmo rs. `SELECT temp.id_nao_encontrado FROM (
  SELECT 10 as id_nao_encontrado FROM DUAL 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 20 FROM DUAL 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 30 FROM DUAL 
 ) AS temp  
WHERE temp.id_nao_encontrado NOT IN (SELECT id from teste);` . Para testes: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/812b5/9

Comment: Valeu, aproveitei seu schema no meu demo. Eu não conhecia esse `FROM DUAL`, mas pelo que vi ele é opcional no MySQL (SELECTs sem FROM são válidos).

Comment: @bfavaretto Até onde eu sei, `FROM DUAL` é requerido apenas no Oracle.

Comment: @utluiz Tá explicado por que eu não conhecia :)

Comment: Sim, apenas requerido no oracle (apenas para documentação): `DUAL is purely for the convenience of people who require that all SELECT statements should have FROM and possibly other clauses. MySQL may ignore the clauses. MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables are referenced.`

Answer (score -1):

Poderia utilizar algo assim

```
SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE id NOT IN (1,23,45,68,91,126,345,418,509,610);
```

Comment: Não funciona porque os ids deletados já não existem no sistema. Precisaria retornar os itens indicados na pesquisa que não encontram correspondente na tabela.