# Obter numero de elementos dependendo do numero máximo de elementos por grupos

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho duas tabelas e pretendo o obter o `name` da tabela `A` dependendo do `Num3`. Por exemplo , na tabela `A`, temos o `num2` e na tabela `B` há os valores correspondentes ao `Num1`.

O que pretendo é que o `name` apareça repetido o número de vezes correspondente ao número máximo de `num3` relacionado com o `num2`.

Por exemplo , o `num2 = 3` tem como `num3` máximo o valor `4`, ou seja queraque ele apareça 4 vezes

Usando estas tabelas:

```
-- A (name,Num2, local)
insert into A values ('Favela',1,'WE');
insert into A values ('Lamosa',2,'NA');
insert into A values ('Luz',3,'S0');

-- B (Num1,name,Num2, Num3) 
insert into B values (1,'Maria',1,1);
insert into B values (2,'Jorge',2,1);
insert into B values (3,'Teresa',2,1);
insert into B values (4,'Rui',3,1);
insert into B values (1,'Fran',3,3);
insert into B values (2,'Juliett',3,3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte `query` se não houverem "buracos" no campo `id_especime`:

```
SELECT x.nome
  FROM (SELECT max(e.id_especime) as maximo_id_especime,
               a.nome
          FROM aquario a
               INNER JOIN especime e ON e.id_aquario = a.id_aquario
         GROUP BY a.id_aquario, a.nome) x
       INNER JOIN especime e ON e.id_especime <= x.maximo_id_especime
 GROUP BY x.nome, e.id_especime
```

---

**Edit**

Após a nova informação fornecida na pergunta, caso queira utilizar a `subquery` apenas no `WHERE` você deve fazer um `CROSS JOIN` que juntará todas as informações da outra tabela e restringi-la no `WHERE`.

```
SELECT a.nome
  FROM aquario a
       CROSS JOIN especime e
 WHERE (SELECT max(e2.id_especime)
          FROM especime e2
         WHERE e2.id_aquario = a.id_aquario) >= e.id_especime
 GROUP BY a.nome, e.id_especime
```

Comment: É possivel fazer isso com a  sub-interrogação fora do From ?

Comment: @ForçaChape O que é uma sub-interrogação?

Comment: o que está no From fazer fora do From

Comment: @ForçaChape não entendi sua intenção. O que está dentro do `FROM` determina o número máximo de interações.

Comment: Sim mas para o que tenho de fazer não pode haver interrogações ( que é o que está no from ) no campo do From , só no where

Comment: @ForçaChape dessa forma não há como, afinal você tem que descobrir o número máximo de alguma forma. Sua pergunta parece estar incompleta, se não deve ser utilizada `subquery` você deve informar isso na pergunta

Comment: deve ser usada subquery , mas não no campo do from , só no do where e também não sei como

Comment: @ForçaChape então coloque isso na pergunta. Sua pergunta não está clara.

Comment: sim sim , eu também só percebi agora

Comment: @ForçaChape veja a segunda solução na parte de baixo da resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Com base na resposta (do Bacco) para a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/como-gerar-sequ%C3%AAncias-num%C3%A9ricas-em-sql-sem-precisar-criar-tabelas), montei um gerador para repetir o *aquario* conforme o *id_especime*, veja:

```
SELECT A.NOME 'AQUARIO' FROM
    (SELECT (D1+D2*10+d3*100)+1 AS GERADOR FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS D1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
         UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T1,
         (SELECT 0 AS D2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
         UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T2,
         (SELECT 0 AS D3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
         UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T3) T
    , AQUARIO A
WHERE T.GERADOR <= (SELECT MAX(E1.ID_ESPECIME) 'MAXIMO'
                    FROM ESPECIME E1 
                    WHERE E1.ID_AQUARIO = A.ID_AQUARIO 
                    GROUP BY E1.ID_AQUARIO)
```

**Observações**

> Ao invés de começar em zero (0), modifiquei para começar em um (1);
>
> O gerador da forma como está, gerará números de 1 até 1000 - pode não ser compatível com seu modelo caso o `ID_ESPECIME` seja maior que 1000 (hoje ou no futuro);