# Gerar linha vazias (null) em sql server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Não possuo muito conhecimento de sql, mas preciso fazer o seguinte procedimento:

- Usuário informa um numero.
- Sql gera a quantidade informada pelo usuario de registros em branco/null.
- Após gerado os registros em branco, executar uma sql para consulta.

No ultimo item a consulta sql eu consigo fazer. Mas preciso saber como executar somente após terminado de gerar os registros em branco.

---

**Caso**: A biblioteca usa uma folha de etiquetas contendo 30 etiquetas. Então se ela usou 5 etiquetas da folha, preciso de 5 registro em branco para nao imprimir nada e a partir do sexto registro comece a imprimir o resultado da consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode gerar uma [tabela com sequências numéricas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/como-gerar-sequ%C3%AAncias-num%C3%A9ricas-em-sql-sem-precisar-criar-tabelas) (omitindo seus dados) e unir com sua pesquisa original.
O `TOP 10` você vai especificar o quanto deseja.

```
WITH gerador (id) AS (
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id + 1
     FROM gerador
     WHERE id < 1000000
  )
  SELECT TOP 10 NULL 'CAMPO_1', NULL 'CAMPO_2', NULL 'CAMPO_3' FROM gerador
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SEU_CAMPO_1, SEU_CAMPO_2, SEU_CAMPO_3 FROM SUA_TABELA
  OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
GO
```

Comment: Nice! Ajudou mt!

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, e se for contrário, os registro do Select vindo antes das linhas NULL, limitando um valor máximo de linhas(10 por exemplo). Isto é, as linhas NULL dinâmicas, se os registro apresentarem 8 linhas, a query deve trazer apenas 2 linhas NULL se considerar um limite de 10 linhas de espaço.