# Retornar resultados para todos os meses do intervalo

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu possuo a seguinte `query`:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN (ta2.time_unit * 1.5)/60 ELSE ta2.time_unit/60 END) as DECIMAL(12,2)) AS TEMPO_CORRETO,
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time) AS MES,
    MONTH(ta2.change_time) AS NUMEROMES,
    t2.customer_id as EMPRESA
FROM 
    otrs.ticket t2
    LEFT JOIN otrs.time_accounting as ta2 ON t2.id = ta2.ticket_id
    LEFT JOIN otrs.ticket_type as tt2 ON t2.type_id = tt2.id
    LEFT JOIN otrs.service as s2 ON t2.service_id = s2.id   
WHERE
    ta2.change_time between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-30' AND
    t2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ' AND
    tt2.name = 'CONTRATO PCH'
GROUP BY 
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time),
    MONTH(ta2.change_time),
    EMPRESA
ORDER BY 
    NUMEROMES
```

E estou obtendo o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém na minha `query` estou selecionando o período de Janeiro a Abril, mas em janeiro não possuo registro minha necessidade seria retornar o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/como-gerar-sequências-numéricas-em-sql-sem-precisar-criar-tabelas

Comment: qual o Database utilizado?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis o que eu realmente preciso é o mês, eu posso me basear com aquilo?

Comment: Mas como eu poderia fazer isso @RovannLinhalis?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, é o MySQL 6.3

Comment: Relacionado: [Como montar esse SQL para trazer meses que não estão na lista?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300661/como-montar-esse-sql-para-trazer-meses-que-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A3o-na-lista).

Comment: R.Santos nada ainda cara ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis nada ainda :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa gerar a sequencia de meses:

```
SELECT m.mes, MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(m.mes, '%m')) AS nome_mes
FROM (
SELECT d1+d2*10 AS mes FROM
   (SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t1,
   (SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t2
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 1 ) AS m
```

Depois você dá o select na tabela de meses, com o outer join na sua tabela de dados, ficaria algo assim:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN (ta2.time_unit * 1.5)/60 ELSE ta2.time_unit/60 END) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS TEMPO_CORRETO,
    MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(m.mes, '%m')) AS MES,
    m.mes AS NUMEROMES,
    t2.customer_id AS EMPRESA
FROM 
    SELECT d1+d2*10 AS mes FROM
   (SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t1,
   (SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t2
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 1 ) AS m   
    LEFT JOIN otrs.time_accounting AS ta2 ON MONTH(ta2.change_time) = m.mes
    LEFT JOIN otrs.ticket t2 ON t2.id = ta2.ticket_id
    LEFT JOIN otrs.ticket_type AS tt2 ON t2.type_id = tt2.id
    LEFT JOIN otrs.service AS s2 ON t2.service_id = s2.id   
WHERE
    ta2.change_time BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-30' AND
    t2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ' AND
    tt2.name = 'CONTRATO PCH'
GROUP BY 
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time),
    MONTH(ta2.change_time),
    EMPRESA
ORDER BY 
    NUMEROMES
```

ps. Não levei em consideração o ano

Update: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2ZF2RRDH8DMb7QyrfBx1Vg/0

Após muita conversa (vide chat) cheguei a uma query que acredito seja a solução:

```
select

m.mes,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN (coalesce(ta.time_unit,0) * 1.5)/ 60 ELSE coalesce(ta.time_unit,0)/60 END) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS TEMPO_CORRETO,
tk2.customer_id

From

(Select 1 as mes union Select 2 union Select 3 union Select 4 union Select 5 union Select 6 union Select 7 union Select 8 union Select 9 union Select 10 union Select 11 union Select 12) as m

left outer join time_accounting ta on MONTH(ta.change_time) = m.mes 
left outer join ticket tk2 on ta.ticket_id = tk2.id 
                           and tk2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ' 
                           and tk2.type_id = 11
left outer join service AS s ON tk2.service_id = s.id

WHERE m.mes BETWEEN MONTH('2018-01-01') AND MONTH('2018-07-30')


GROUP BY m.mes,tk2.customer_id

order by m.mes
```

Disponível no [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLyt4ABZhe6uUgodU4pxAY/5)

> *EDIT: 28/05/2018*

Refiz a query, dessa vez mostrando o nome do cliente em todas as linhas, mesmo que não tenha registros no mês:

```
SELECT
MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(meses.mes, '%m')) AS MES,
meses.mes as mes_numero,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN ( coalesce(ta.time_unit,0) * 1.5)/ 60 ELSE coalesce(ta.time_unit,0)/60 END) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS TEMPO_CORRETO,
meses.customer_id as empresa
FROM
(Select distinct
  m.mes,
  t2.customer_id
From (SELECT d1+d2*10 AS mes FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t1, 
(SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) t2 
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 1 ) AS m
Cross Join ticket t2
WHERE t2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ') as meses
LEFT JOIN ticket t on t.customer_id = meses.customer_id
                   and t.type_id = 11
LEFT JOIN time_accounting ta on ta.ticket_id = t.id 
                             and MONTH(ta.change_time) = meses.mes
                             and ta.change_time BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-30'

LEFT JOIN service AS s2 ON t.service_id = s2.id
WHERE meses.mes BETWEEN MONTH('2018-01-01') AND MONTH('2018-07-30')
GROUP BY   meses.mes, meses.customer_id    
ORDER BY meses.mes
```

> Resultado:

```
mes_numero  TEMPO_CORRETO   empresa
1           0               ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ
2           7.39            ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ
3           23.29           ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ
4           3.18            ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ
5           0               ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ
6           0               ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ
7           0               ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ
```

Coloquei no [**DBFiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5a29nvrTJ95pDGRaiVMkqm/2)

Comment: Mas como consigo executar isso Rovann? Executo um select de cada vez.

Comment: o segundo select, já está com o primeiro dentro... executa só o segundo select que deve resolver

Comment: Ah sim kk, executei e deu o seguinte erro: `Error Code: 1630. FUNCTION t2.MONTH does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual`

Comment: Eu consegui executar Rovann mas o resultado da query continuou o mesmo, ou seja, não trouxe o mês de janeiro por não ter registros nesse mês

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77709/discussion-between-r-santos-and-rovann-linhalis).

Comment: Conseguimos falar por bate papo Rovann?

Comment: @R.Santos tente novamente com a última query

Comment: Perfeito Rovann, muito obrigado pela ajuda, Eu ofereci uma nova recompensa para te dar mas só em 23 horas eu posso te passar ela, mas assim que liberar eu te passo os ponto. Novamente muito obrigado

Comment: tranquilo nem precisava de tantos pontos haha, importante é que resolveu

Comment: Capaz, foi uma baita mão, merece até mais

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma tabela de meses, já que facilitaria sua vida:

```
CREATE TABLE mes (
  id INT,
  mes VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO mes VALUES(1, 'JANEIRO'),
                      (2, 'FEVEREIRO'),
                      (3, 'MARÇO'),
                      (4, 'ABRIL'),
                      (5, 'MAIO'),
                      (6, 'JUNHO'),
                      (7, 'JULHO'),
                      (8, 'AGOSTO'),
                      (9, 'SETEMBRO'),
                      (10, 'OUTUBRO'),
                      (11, 'NOVEMBRO'),
                      (12, 'DEZEMBRO');
```

Depois disso utilize essa tabela criada diretamente no `FROM`, assim você pode mostrar os valores independente dos vínculos com as demais tabelas:

```
...
FROM mes m
...
```

No próximo passo vincule as demais tabelas com `LEFT JOIN`, o que irá limitar a obrigatoriedade:

```
...
LEFT JOIN time_accounting AS ta2 ON MONTH(ta2.change_time) = m.id
LEFT JOIN ticket t2 ON t2.id = ta2.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN ticket_type AS tt2 ON t2.type_id = tt2.id
LEFT JOIN service AS s2 ON t2.service_id = s2.id
...
```

No `WHERE` você deve considerar que as tabelas utilizadas no `LEFT` podem ter **OU NÃO** registros, portanto deve-se verificar se é `NULL`:

```
...
WHERE (t2.id IS NULL OR t2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ') 
  AND (tt2.id IS NULL OR tt2.name = 'CONTRATO PCH') 
...
```

Aconselho que o filtro de data seja feio por mês, assim o que não estiver dentro do filtro não será mostrado:

```
...
AND m.id BETWEEN MONTH('2018-01-01') AND MONTH('2018-07-30')
...
```

A `query` resultante seria:

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.mes,
       CAST(SUM(CASE
                  WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN (ta2.time_unit * 1.5) / 60
                  ELSE ta2.time_unit/60
                END) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS TEMPO_CORRETO,
       t2.customer_id AS EMPRESA
  FROM mes m
  LEFT JOIN time_accounting AS ta2 ON MONTH(ta2.change_time) = m.id
  LEFT JOIN ticket t2 ON t2.id = ta2.ticket_id
  LEFT JOIN ticket_type AS tt2 ON t2.type_id = tt2.id
  LEFT JOIN service AS s2 ON t2.service_id = s2.id
 WHERE (t2.id IS NULL OR t2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ')
   AND (tt2.id IS NULL OR tt2.name = 'CONTRATO PCH')
   AND m.id BETWEEN MONTH('2018-01-01') AND MONTH('2018-07-30')
 GROUP BY m.mes, m.id, t2.customer_id
 ORDER BY m.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Correção:
Adicione outra condição  `AND
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN (ta2.time_unit * 1.5)/60 ELSE ta2.time_unit/60 END) as DECIMAL(12,2)) > 0`

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN (ta2.time_unit * 1.5)/60 ELSE ta2.time_unit/60 END) as DECIMAL(12,2)) AS TEMPO_CORRETO,
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time) AS MES,
    MONTH(ta2.change_time) AS NUMEROMES,
    t2.customer_id as EMPRESA
FROM 
    otrs.ticket t2
    LEFT JOIN otrs.time_accounting as ta2 ON t2.id = ta2.ticket_id
    LEFT JOIN otrs.ticket_type as tt2 ON t2.type_id = tt2.id
    LEFT JOIN otrs.service as s2 ON t2.service_id = s2.id   
WHERE
    ta2.change_time between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-30' AND
    t2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ' AND
    tt2.name = 'CONTRATO PCH' AND
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN (ta2.time_unit * 1.5)/60 ELSE ta2.time_unit/60 END) as DECIMAL(12,2)) > 0
GROUP BY 
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time),
    MONTH(ta2.change_time),
    EMPRESA
ORDER BY 
    NUMEROMES
```

Comment: Ocorreu o seguinte erro Marcelo: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'TEMPO_CORRETO' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Sem contar que o que eu preciso é retornar os meses que não possuem registros, e na sua resposta é feito o contrario

Comment: De fato não é possível usar o alias ali no where, então a solução seria usar a condição toda, conforme correção que fiz agora.

Comment: Mas na sua resposta eu seleciono somente quando o mês possui algum registro e o que eu quero é que mesmo que o mês não possua nenhum registro.

Answer (score -1):

Se você inverter a tabela `otrs.ticket t2` com a `otrs.time_accounting ta2` não daria certo?

**Editado**

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN (ta2.time_unit * 1.5)/60 ELSE ta2.time_unit/60 END) as DECIMAL(12,2)) AS TEMPO_CORRETO,
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time) AS MES,
    MONTH(ta2.change_time) AS NUMEROMES,
    t2.customer_id as EMPRESA
FROM 
    otrs.time_accounting ta2
    LEFT JOIN otrs.ticket t2 ON t2.id = ta2.ticket_id
    LEFT JOIN otrs.ticket_type as tt2 ON t2.type_id = tt2.id
    LEFT JOIN otrs.service as s2 ON t2.service_id = s2.id   
WHERE
    ta2.change_time between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-30' AND
    coalesce(t2.customer_id, 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ') = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ' AND
    coalesce(tt2.name, 'CONTRATO PCH')            = 'CONTRATO PCH'
GROUP BY 
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time),
    MONTH(ta2.change_time),
    EMPRESA
ORDER BY 
    NUMEROMES
```

Tente utilizar o `coalesce` também, tente dar uma adequada para o seu caso para ver se funciona.

Comment: Ele continua trazendo somente os meses onde há registros mateus, eu preciso que quando não houver registro no mês igual seja retornado esse mês

Comment: Verifique se a alteração resolve!