# Resultado da Consulta vir Zerado

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Boa Tarde,

Estou com uma dúvida, poderiam me ajudar? ...

Oque ocorre é:

tenho uma consulta sql que me traz  a quantidade total de sms enviado por mês e ano, porém gostaria de quando eu não tivesse resultado naquele mês mostra-se zero no campo. porque atualmente ele some e não mostra.

EX:
ATUALMENTE
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SQL :

```
    SELECT   Count(*) QtdSMSEnviadoPorMes,                 
             MONTH(DataAgendada) AS MES, 
             YEAR(DataAgendada) ANO
        FROM tblLoteTESTE 
            WHERE CodCampanha = 1
        GROUP BY MONTH(DataAgendada),YEAR(DataAgendada )
```

Gostaria de mostra-se assim ex: mes 11  0

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: desculpe mas não entendi, me parecem iguais os resultados, tirando o valor da linha 11 borrado de vermelho

Comment: Então esse borrada de vermelho fiz como exemplo um zero ! Rs 
EX:caso não tenha registro no mês de novembro me mostre 0

@RicardoPontual

Comment: você tem que dar o select nos meses... com left join com seus registros. Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/300026/69359 talvez seja até uma pergunta duplicata, salvo o sgdb que é diferente

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Mas meus registros estão em uma tabela só

Comment: Veja a resposta da outra pergunta, não existe tabela de meses lá também

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Desculpá minha ignorância, mas sou leigo na área não consegui resolver ainda.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis consegui de outra forma obrigado.

Comment: Veja se ajuda , union com dados "zerados" , sequencia artificial  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/99190dd6-17a7-4c70-8d6a-b30a8910b8ac/gerar-sequencia-de-datas?forum=520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como disse, você precisa selecionar os meses, e depois selecionar seus dados.

Os meses você pode gerar sequências numéricas de 1 a 12, ou ir dando select union.

Considerando o seguinte cenário:

```
create table tblLoteTESTE 
(
  id integer,
  DataAgendada datetime,
);


insert into tblLoteTESTE values (1, '01/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (2, '02/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (3, '03/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (4, '04/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (5, '04/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (6, '06/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (7, '07/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (8, '07/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (9, '07/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (10, '10/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (11, '11/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (12, '12/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (13, '12/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (14, '10/01/2018');
insert into tblLoteTESTE values (15, '06/01/2018');
```

Sua query deve ficar assim:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, m.mes-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime))) as 
    mes_nome,
    m.mes,
    count(t.id) as qtd
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS mes
   UNION SELECT 2
   UNION SELECT 3
   UNION SELECT 4
   UNION SELECT 5
   UNION SELECT 6
   UNION SELECT 7
   UNION SELECT 8
   UNION SELECT 9
   UNION SELECT 10
   UNION SELECT 11
   UNION SELECT 12 ) AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblLoteTESTE t ON MONTH(t.DataAgendada) = m.mes and YEAR(t.DataAgendada) = 2018
group by m.mes
```

Resultado:

```
mes_nome    mes qtd
January     1   1
February    2   1
March       3   1
April       4   2
May         5   0
June        6   2
July        7   3
August      8   0
September   9   0
October     10  2
November    11  1
December    12  2
```

> Repare que não entrou o ano, pois teria que gerar a sequencia dos anos, com um cross join nos meses, para então contar os registros. O que me parece desnecessário. Esse tipo de informação normalmente é vista ano a ano, portanto basta informar o ano desejado como filtro.

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/961f8/4)