# Query em mysql agrupando por dias com count retornando valor 0 se não houver o dia

Tags: mysql

Bom dia estou fazendo uma consulta no db da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) as numero, DAY(cdr.calldate) as dia, MONTH(cdr.calldate) as mes, YEAR(cdr.calldate) as ano FROM cdr LEFT JOIN peers on cdr.dst = peers.name WHERE cdr.calldate >= '2018-08-01 00:00:00' and cdr.calldate <= '2018-08-23 23:59:59' and length(src) > 5 and dcontext = 'default' and (cdr.dst like '2209' OR cdr.dstchannel like 'KHOMP/b0c9%') GROUP BY DAY(cdr.calldate)
```

ele me traz o seguinte resultado:

```
numero  dia mes ano
4       1   8   2018
14      6   8   2018
20      7   8   2018
10      8   8   2018
19      9   8   2018
10      10  8   2018
17      13  8   2018
9       14  8   2018
13      15  8   2018
9       16  8   2018
10      17  8   2018
10      20  8   2018
16      21  8   2018
3       22  8   2018
1       23  8   2018
```

Repare que ele não traz alguns dias por não haver informação destes dias.
Ja pesquisei na internet e não consegui fazer trazer os dias que não tem resultados como valor 0 no count.
Alguém sabe como fazer? ou pode me dizer qual o nome da função no mysql ou comando que retorna isso?

Comment: nessa resposta, está mostrando como fazer com meses. A lógica é a mesma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/300026/69359 basicamente, você precisa ter todos os dias, e dar left join com as outras tabelas.

Comment: entendi entao vou gerar uma tabela com todo calendário do ano ou pelo menos vou ter que bolar um for no php que faz uma consulta por dia.

Comment: o intervalo de dias você determina, fiz esse exemplo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jmTZtkNZqnErDZAQKhtGfU/0

Comment: muito legau da para eu fazer a query em tempo real. como eu troco esse seu ex para inserir uma data incial e outra final ?

Comment: aí você precisa calcular a diferença de dias entre as duas datas, alterar o limit para essa diferença, e colocar a data inicial onde está now no exemplo. Estou ocupado no momento mas em breve, se ninguém o fiz, farei uma resposta

Comment: legau mas vo tenta aki pelo menos vc ja m disse o caminho das pedras. muito obrigado.