# Select retornar resultado mesmo se não houver registro NULL, agrupado por dia

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um select que retorna um conjunto de dados por DATA.
Exemplo:
[image]

Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, não existe dados para os dias: `20,21,22...28`

Gostaria de trazer essas linhas com resultado `"NULLO"`

Meu select é simples, a coluna data tem data POR dia

```
SELECT * 
from rentabilidade_fundos 
where data BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-31' 
order by data
```

Comment: Você não consegue recuperar dados que não existem em sua tabela. Uma solução é utilizar uma tabela auxiliar com todos os dias do período desejado e fazer um LEFT OUTER JOIN com sua tabela utilizando a data como critério da junção. Se, além disso, utilizar a função COALESCE poderá exibir o que desejar caso o campo seja NULL.

Comment: veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/300026/69359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia gerar os dados do mês em uma tabela auxiliar.
Como exemplo, da pra fazer isso usando "tabelas" do próprio MySql:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2020-04-01', INTERVAL rnk day) dia 
  FROM (SELECT row_number() over() -1 rnk 
          FROM information_schema.columns limit 31) gerado
```

Depois é só fazer um `LEFT OUTER JOIN` dessa tabela auxiliar com a sua query:

```
WITH dias AS (
SELECT DATE_ADD('2020-04-01', INTERVAL rnk DAY) dia 
  FROM (SELECT row_number() over() -1 rnk 
          FROM information_schema.columns LIMIT 31) gerado)


SELECT dias.dia, r.fundo_conservador, r.fundo_moderado, r.fundo_arrojado
  FROM dias
  LEFT OUTER JOIN rentabilidade_fundos r
    ON r.data = dias.dia
 WHERE dias.dia BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-31' 
 ORDER BY dias.dia
```

Veja rodando [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da455ad7ead30402c7ef1e4cb64fee8d).