# Selecionar os últimos meses, mostrando também os meses sem registros

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá.

Estou fazendo um SELECT para retornar os últimos 06 meses, mostrando a contagem de registros (no exemplo: vendas), agrupando por ano-mês.

Minha consulta atualmente está assim:

```
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

CREATE TABLE vendas (
   id INT NOT NULL,
   data_venda DATE NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE (id)
);

INSERT INTO vendas
   (id, data_venda)
VALUES
    (1, '2020-10-01'),
    (2, '2020-10-01'),
    (3, '2020-12-01'),
    (4, '2020-12-01'),
    (5, '2020-12-01'),
    (6, '2020-12-01'),
    (7, '2021-02-01'),
    (8, '2021-02-01'),
    (9, '2021-02-01'),
    (10, '2021-02-01'),
    (11, '2021-02-01'),
    (12, '2021-03-01'),
    (13, '2021-03-01'),
    (14, '2021-03-01'),
    (15, '2021-03-01'),
    (16, '2021-04-01');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(data_venda, "%Y-%m") AS ano_mes,
    COUNT(id)
FROM
    vendas
WHERE
    /* Utilize o NOW para mudar automaticamente,
    * deixei fixo 2021-04-30 para o exemplo
    * ainda funcionar no futuro.
    */
    /* data_venda >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) */
    data_venda >= DATE_SUB('2020-04-30', INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(data_venda, "%Y-%m");
```

| ano_mes | COUNT(id) |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12 | 4 |
| 2021-02 | 5 |
| 2021-03 | 4 |
| 2021-04 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/efvQEZzv8Qc8rkswZseyvJ/1)

Repare que, para ser os últimos 06 meses, deveria retornar também o mês 2020-11 e 2021-01, mostrando como 0 (zero). Assim:

| ano_mes | COUNT(id) |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11 | 0 |
| 2020-12 | 4 |
| 2021-01 | 0 |
| 2021-02 | 5 |
| 2021-03 | 4 |
| 2021-04 | 1 |

Já pensei em fazer o tratamento após a consulta, diretamente na programação do sistema (criar uma função para corrigir o retorno do SELECT, direto em PHP, por exemplo). Mas me parece ficar mais legível e simples se a consulta já vier completa (com meses zerados).

Acredito que a correção passa por algum SUBSELECT que construa os último 06 meses e depois combine com o meu SELECT atual (exemplo acima), mas não estou conseguindo fazer. Vi algumas perguntas aqui, mas também não consegui aplicar a resposta. Algumas falavam em criar um procedure ou ajustavam o mês dentro de um ano fixo, mas repare que nesse caso tem dois anos envolvidos.

Obrigado a quem puder auxiliar. ✌

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Retornar resultados para todos os meses do intervalo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300015/retornar-resultados-para-todos-os-meses-do-intervalo)

Comment: Obrigado, Sorack. Mas ainda tenho o problema do ano mudar, certo? Tente aplicar com a criação da lista de 12 meses criada na resposta indicada, mas a query não sabe a qual ano o mês criado pertence.
Talvez a saída seja criar uma tabela base de datas (deixar ela lá no meu banco de dados), com todos os meses e anos possíveis (até uma data bem longa no futuro), e filtrar a partir dela. Mas gostaria do apoio de quem tem mais conhecimento, se essa é uma opção boa ou seria uma saída fácil/gambiarra.

Comment: Qual versão do MySQL você está usando?

Comment: v5.7, mesma do exemplo na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sugerido no comentário pelo @Sorack, é preciso gerar uma sequencia de datas e fazer o LEFT JOIN (ou RIGHT JOIN dependendo do lado que estão as datas geradas) com tabela de vendas.

Eu uso um exemplo baseado nesse link: https://www.shayanderson.com/mysql/generating-a-series-of-dates-in-mysql.htm

Aqui para referência:

```
SELECT DATE(cal.date)
FROM (
      SELECT SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) + INTERVAL xc DAY AS date
      FROM (
            SELECT @xi:=@xi+1 as xc from
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc1,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc2,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc3,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc4,
            (SELECT @xi:=-1) xc0
      ) xxc1
) cal
WHERE cal.date <= NOW()
ORDER BY cal.date DESC
```

Basicamente esse código faz o seguinte: os `SELECT` com `UNION` geram números sequenciais, por causa da variável `@xi` que é somada. Repare que, cada bloco de `SELECT` gera 4 números, e eles são juntos (`UNION`) como se fosse "FROM", mas como não há relação entre eles, é feito um cartesiano, ou seja, o cada `SELECT` gera 4 números, então 4x4x4x4 = 256, e a variável "conta" isso, gerando valores de 0 a 255. Logo, só podem se geradas datas num intervalo de 256, nesse caso dias (veja o intervalo `+ INTERVAL xc DAY`). Para gerar mais valores, basta aumentar o `UNION` ou adicionar mais "tabelas" (xc5, xc6, etc).

A partir daí, como só precisa de mês ano, podemos agrupar isso e usar `DATE_SUB`, como no seu exemplo:

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) + INTERVAL xc DAY, "%Y-%m") AS data
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT @xi:=@xi+1 as xc from
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc1,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc2,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc3,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc4,
            (SELECT @xi:=-1) xc0
      ) xxc1
```

Isso vai gerar os pares de mês-ano (usei o DISTICT para remover os duplicados, afinal foi gerado a partir de uma data, ou teria de agrupar), algo assim:

```
| data    |
| ------- |
| 2020-11 |
| 2020-12 |
| 2021-01 |
| 2021-02 |
| 2021-03 |
| 2021-04 |
```

Agora que temos as datas, basta fazer um `LEFT JOIN` (nesse caso, essas datas ficarão à esquerda no JOIN, para trazer inclusive os dados não existentes em "vendas")

```
SELECT cal.data,
       IFNULL(vda.tot, 0) tot
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) + INTERVAL xc DAY, "%Y-%m") AS data
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT @xi:=@xi+1 as xc from
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc1,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc2,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc3,
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc4,
            (SELECT @xi:=-1) xc0
      ) xxc1
  ) cal 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(data_venda, "%Y-%m") AS ano_mes, 
      COUNT(id) tot 
    FROM 
      vendas 
    WHERE 
      data_venda >= DATE_SUB('2020-04-30', INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
    GROUP BY 
      DATE_FORMAT(data_venda, "%Y-%m")
  ) vda on vda.ano_mes = data  
WHERE cal.data <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m")
ORDER BY cal.data
```

Algumas observações:

- a tabela "vendas" foi adiciona como subquery, com alias "vda";
- para retornar zero quando não encontrar um períodos, foi usado a função `IFNULL`, quer retorna o primeiro valor e, caso seja nulo, retorna o segundo, nesse caso zero (0);

Pode ver funcionando aqui: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUbg5HjhdpS819VHfLxDq/1

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado pela ajuda e explicação, realmente não conhecia essa utilização das variáveis (utilização e manipulação/cálculo), vou me aprofundar no assunto.