# Procurar intervalo de registros faltantes

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Imaginem a seguinte situação: uma tabela está assim:

```
Id (int) - Codigo (int) - Descricao (varchar)
1        -      01      - Descrição 1
2        -      03      - Descrição 2
3        -      04      - Descrição 3
4        -      05      - Descrição 4
```

Reparem que entre o Id 1 e 2 está faltando o código "02". Estou procurando uma maneira para descobrir se existe um "código disponível" entre os registros da tabela e mostrar numa TextBox, mas não estou conseguindo organizar a ideia pra fazer essa query. Estou usando o Linq.
Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa?
Abraços a todos.

Comment: Tabela.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Codigo == "02"); // seleciona o código "02" ou nulo (se não existir)
Tabela.Select(o => o.Codigo).ToList()  // seleciona todos os códigos

Comment: O `Codigo` acompanha sempre o `Id`? Ou seja, um possível Id 9 terá o código "09" ou pode ter um Id 9 e código "11" (por exemplo)?

Comment: João, sim, o Id não tem nada a ver com o Código.

Comment: Então como se conseguirá saber que existe uma "falha" entre os códigos? O código é sequencial?

Comment: Não, o código não é sequencial. Justamente o que eu preciso é isso, nos registros da tabela, à partir do primeiro, encontrar qual registro onde há uma "quebra" de sequência. Encontrei uma solução, mas o código está em SQL, precisava "converter" para Linq, mas não estou conseguindo. Vou deixar aqui, quem sabe você ou outro colega possa me ajudar:
Select
      t1.codigogrupo + 1 as livre
FROM grupo AS t1
LEFT JOIN grupo AS t2 on t1.codigogrupo + 1 = t2.codigogrupo
where
t2.CodigoGrupo IS NULL AND t1.CodigoGrupo > 1

Comment: Você vai precisar criar um conjunto com todos os itens intermediarios entre o menor e o maior codigo que você tem, e depois fazer uma seleção de quais deles não existem no seu conjunto original, onde estariam as lacunas.

Comment: No caso, o item de id 5 receberia o código "02"? porque você precisa dessa sequencia com essa relação fraca?

Comment: Acho que **[essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/como-gerar-sequ%C3%AAncias-num%C3%A9ricas-em-sql-sem-precisar-criar-tabelas)** tá relacionada ao mesmo problema, mas com a perspectiva do banco em vez de linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embora não me pareça que essa seja a solução para o seu problema, essa é uma resposta para sua pergunta.

Veja dois exemplso de como encontrar o primeiro intervalo/buraco em um conjunto de códigos representados como `string`, mas que podem ser convertidos em inteiros.

Utilizando `Linq`, `Range()` e `Except()` com apenas algumas validações adicionais.

```
string[] codigos = { "01", "03", "05", "04" };

List<int> codigosConvertidos = codigos.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
int intervaloEncontrado = 1;
int valorMaximo = codigosConvertidos.Max();

if (valorMaximo > 0)
    intervaloEncontrado = Enumerable.Range(codigosConvertidos.Min(), codigosConvertidos.Count()).Except(codigosConvertidos).FirstOrDefault();                                   

int primeiroCodigoDisponivel = intervaloEncontrado > 0 ? intervaloEncontrado : valorMaximo + 1;

string resultado = primeiroCodigoDisponivel.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

E abaixo deixo outro exemplo utilizando o `Linq` apenas para ordernar o vetor

```
string[] codigos = { "01", "03", "05", "04" };

var inteirosOrdenados = codigos.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

int? codigoAnterior = null;
int? intervaloEncontrado = null;

int tamanhoVetor = inteirosOrdenados.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++)
{
    if (codigoAnterior != null)
    {
        int intervaloEsperado = inteirosOrdenados[i] - 1;

        if (intervaloEsperado != codigoAnterior)
        {
            intervaloEncontrado = intervaloEsperado;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            codigoAnterior = inteirosOrdenados[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        codigoAnterior = inteirosOrdenados[i];
    }

}

if (intervaloEncontrado == null)
    intervaloEncontrado = inteirosOrdenados[tamanhoVetor - 1] + 1;

string resultado = intervaloEncontrado.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```