# Buscar primeiro espaço vazio no banco de dados

Tags: c#, mysql

Tenho uma pequena aplicação em C#, que cria o código do fornecedor automático.
Queria saber se alguém sabe alguma forma do sistema buscar um código vazio, ex:

> **1** - Manoel
>
> **2** - Narciso
>
> **4** - Mustela

O próximo código que ele deveria puxar seria o **3**, mais ele sempre vai para o último registro.
Segue abaixo o código:

```
private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Id = txtID.Text;
    string Nome = txtNome.Text;
    string CNPJ = txtCNPJ.Text;
    if (txtNome.Text == "" || txtCNPJ.Text=="" )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Favor informar os dados para cadastro!", "Alerta",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        return;
    }
 
    try
    {
        CONEXAO.Open();
        comando = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO fornecedores (ID, Nome, CNPJ)" + "VALUES ('"
            + Id + "','" + Nome + "','" + CNPJ + "')", CONEXAO);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(Id, txtID.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(Nome, txtNome.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(CNPJ, txtCNPJ.Text);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // Registra os fornecedores no Data Grid.
        registraFornecedor(txtID.Text, txtNome.Text, Convert.ToString(txtCNPJ.Text));
        ClearControls();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A conexão com o banco de dados falhou");
    }
    finally
    {
        CONEXAO.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não responde o que você quer, mas de forma geral isso é ruim, e mesmo que queira insistir precisa tomar muitos cuidados que vão além do que está postando nesta pergunta. O meu medo é alguém responder a forma ingênua que parece certa, mas só funciona por coincidência, a não ser que não tenha concorrência, o que é altamente improvável. Geralmente para fazer isso direito precisa de um sofisticado sistema de controle próprio.

Comment: Concordo com o Maniero, a resposta para o que quer é complexa, mas tentando ajudar devo lhe dizer que você deve repensar a lógica, evite designar um código antes do usuário confirmar os dados e antes de você fazer as consistências, ou você faz um campo auto-incremento e depois resgata o valor ou cria uma função generator para ser usada em todas as telas que irá inserir nessa tabela. Manter a integridade sequencial de um campo que não é auto-incremento não é tarefa simples.

Comment: apenas complementando os outros comentários: e totalmente desnecessário fazer algo assim

Comment: Rovann pelo código exemplo ele está usando MySQL, um campo auto-incremento resolveria o problema, mas vamos supor que ele estivesse usando DBF ele não teria essa facilidade, antigamente esses campos eram controlados na unha, dava um trabalho danado. Ainda tenho clientes que me questionam um numero de pedido que perdeu o sequencial por algum motivo, eu o convenço de que não deve se prender a sequencia, já que temos relatórios  e o "numero sequencial" do pedido é o que menos importa, a não ser que seja número da NF aí muda a coisa.

Comment: Estou usando auto-incremento, porém já vi essa função que pedi ajuda, no delphi, agora no c# não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Reforço as observações do Maniero, dê uma olhada nessa outra pergunta, talvez possa lhe ajudar de alguma forma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324399/procurar-intervalo-de-registros-faltantes/324508#324508