# Como Mostrar número de dias de cada mês no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados `mysql` com duas datas `data_inicial` e `data_final`.

```
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| id | data_inicial         | data_final          |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2022-01-12 15:00:00  | 2022-03-18 19:30:00 |
```

Como faço para mostrar os minutos que faltam em cada mês até a data final. Como na tabela abaixo.

```
+----+---------+
| mes| minutos | 
+----+---------+
| 1  |   27840 |
| 2  |   40260 |
| 3  |   25620 |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nas [funções de Data do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html), vai achar muita coisa útil.
Pro seu caso acredito que daria para fazer alguma coisa com [essa](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), [essa](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff),[essa](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) e talvez [essa](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute)

Comment: Obrigado @Diego_F darei uma olhada nas suas sugestões.

Comment: Faltaria um artifício para gerar sequencias numéricas ou de data.  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/como-gerar-sequ%C3%AAncias-num%C3%A9ricas-em-sql-sem-precisar-criar-tabelas

Answer (score -2):

Opa isso pode te ajudar
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,data_inicial,data_final)

segue link de uma explicação de forma didática https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).