# Query MySQL retornando de forma diferente

Tags: mysql

Possuo o seguinte `Query`:

```
select 
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time) as mes,
    MONTH(ta2.change_time) as numeroMes,
    case 
        when s2.name like '%Servidores' then cast(SUM(ta2.time_unit) as UNSIGNED) * 1.5  else cast(SUM(ta2.time_unit) as UNSIGNED)
    end as TEMPO_CORRETO
from 
    otrs.service s2,
    otrs.time_accounting ta2,
    otrs.ticket t2,
    otrs.ticket_type tt2
where
    t2.id = ta2.ticket_id and
    t2.type_id = tt2.id and
    t2.service_id = s2.id and
    ta2.change_time between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-30' and
    t2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ' and
    tt2.name = 'Contrato PCH'
group by 
    t2.customer_id,
    s2.name
order by 
    numeroMes
```

Porém estou tendo o seguinte retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu gostaria de agrupar esses valores por mês, tendo um resulta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei de tudo mas não consegui ainda, se tiverem uma ideia.

Comment: primeiro precisa incluir `mes, numeroMes` no `group by`, mas o que quer fazer com o `tempo_correto`? Precisar usar alguma função de agregação nele, `sum`, `avg`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá pra simplificar aquela expessão alí da terceira coluna (virou primeira, de acordo com o seu requisito).

Você precisa agrupar pelas colunas que serão tratadas como 'totalizadoras'.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s2.name LIKE '%Servidores' THEN ta2.time_unit * 1.5 ELSE ta2.time_unit END ) AS UNSIGNED) AS TEMPO_CORRETO
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time) AS MES,
    MONTH(ta2.change_time) AS NUMEROMES
FROM 
    otrs.service s2,
    otrs.time_accounting ta2,
    otrs.ticket t2,
    otrs.ticket_type tt2
WHERE
    t2.id = ta2.ticket_id AND
    t2.type_id = tt2.id AND
    t2.service_id = s2.id AND
    ta2.change_time between '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-30' AND
    t2.customer_id = 'ZSCHIMMER SCHWARZ' AND
    tt2.name = 'CONTRATO PCH'
GROUP BY 
    MONTHNAME(ta2.change_time),
    MONTH(ta2.change_time)
ORDER BY 
    NUMEROMES
```

**Importante:** Essa consulta não está tratando a possibilidade de haver registros do mesmo mês em anos diferentes. Veja se esse não seria o caso para a sua regra de negócio.

Comment: Diego só uma dúvida, quando eu coloco um período de `'2018-02-01'` até `'2018-04-30'`, ele me retorna somente o mês de março e abril já que em fevereiro não há registros, é possível que quando não houver registro ele traga o mês mesmo assim e o valor zero no lugar?

Comment: @R.Santos Possível é. Mas é um pouco mais complicado. [Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33828/como-colocar-a-zero-ou-null-numa-pesquisa-sql-de-um-intervalo-de-datas-para-aqu) trata justamente disso. [Nessa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/como-gerar-sequ%C3%AAncias-num%C3%A9ricas-em-sql-sem-precisar-criar-tabelas/33860#33860) tem algumas propostas alternativas também.