# Como montar esse SQL para trazer meses que não estão na lista?

Tags: mysql, sql

O SQL abaixo traz a quantidade de cadastros realizadas mês a mês, até aí blz.
Eu precisava mostrar dos 6 últimos meses, mesmo que fosse zero, mas nesse select ele traria somente quando há registros.

```
select 
  extract(month from data_cad) as mes,
  count(*) as qtd
from mv_clientes
where (ativo not in('C'))
and (data_cad between '2017-12-01' and '2018-05-31')
group by 1
```

Estou usando MySQL, mas não sei vem ao caso, eu poderia ver o SQL em outra base e traduzir pro MySQL

O Result desse SQL é esse

```
mes qtd
3 | 5
4 | 8
5 | 23
```

Eu precisava que fosse:

```
mes qtd
12 | 0 
 1 | 0
 2 | 0
 3 | 5
 4 | 8
 5 | 23
```

Comment: Talvez você possa usar [algo assim](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator) para gerar os meses, e depois fazer um left join com a sua tabela.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como colocar a zero ou null numa pesquisa SQL de um intervalo de datas, para aquelas cujo valor não existe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33828/como-colocar-a-zero-ou-null-numa-pesquisa-sql-de-um-intervalo-de-datas-para-aqu)

Comment: [Nessa pergunta do Maniero algumas sugestões alternativas também foram apresentadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33859/como-gerar-sequ%C3%AAncias-num%C3%A9ricas-em-sql-sem-precisar-criar-tabelas).

Comment: Se eu clicar em "Isso resolveu meu problema" o stack vai retirar a resposta que selecionei como solução abaixo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o `select` vai retornar somente dados existentes, você pode criar uma tabela com os meses e fazer o `left join` com essa tabela, agrupando pelo mês e fazendo o `count` na tabela mv_clientes, assim por exemplo:

```
select x.mes, count(m.data_cad) qtd
  from meses x
  left join mv_clientes m on x.mes = extract(month from m.data_cad)
  group by x.mes
```

Aqui um exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2072d/1

Comment: Boa, essa dica até me deu uma outra ideia, nessa tabela de meses posso ter os meses abreviados e inteiros, Ex, JANEIRO, JAN, dessa forma evito o comando com aquelas velhas rotinas com CASE pra ficar pegando os nomes dos meses

Comment: Eu estava usando UNION pra trazer os meses zero, mas o select fica enorme e horrível

Comment: sim, o `left join` já resolve, e já q fez o join, por os nomes dos mêses já fica fácil

Answer (score 1):

Como não existem linhas para os meses, pode fazer por subqueries:

```
select 
(select count(*) as jan from  mv_clientes where (ativo not in('C'))
and  extract(month from data_cad) = 1 and  extract(year from data_cad) = 2018 JAN,

(select count(*) as jan from  mv_clientes where (ativo not in('C'))
and  extract(month from data_cad) = 2 and  extract(year from data_cad) = 2018 FEV,

(select count(*) as jan from  mv_clientes where (ativo not in('C'))
and  extract(month from data_cad) = 3 and  extract(year from data_cad) = 2018 MAR,

....
(select count(*) as jan from  mv_clientes where (ativo not in('C'))
and  extract(month from data_cad) = 12 and  extract(year from data_cad) = 2018 DEZ
```

sem from

Ou criar uma tabela mv_mes, e fazer uma left join.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo as respostas dos amigos acabei encontrando outra dificuldade, quando faço o select eu preciso ordenar pela data/mês, porém nos meses que não tem nada ele traz zero e não existe data para ordenação, dessa forma não consigo ter o resultado 12/1/2/3/4/5 que seriam os últimos 6 meses.

A solução que cheguei foi a seguinte:

```
select m.indice, m.mes, count(cli.cod_id) as total 
from ( 
select 1 as indice, 05 as mes 
union all 
select 2 as indice, 04 as mes 
union all 
select 3 as indice, 03 as mes 
union all 
select 4 as indice, 02 as mes 
union all 
select 5 as indice, 01 as mes 
union all 
select 6 as indice, 12 as mes ) as m left 
join mv_clientes cli on(extract(month from cli.data_cad) = m.mes) 
and (cli.ativo not in('C')) 
group by 1, 2
order by 1 desc
```

Dessa forma crio um índice e forço a sequencia como quero